# How to avoid code duplication in a Android Test Application?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, reflection, junit

Suppose I have an application that have similar buttons named button0, button1, etc, up to button9.

How can I do the following without duplicating code?

```
button0 = (Button) activity.findViewById(com.sample.SampleApp.R.id.button0);
button1 = (Button) activity.findViewById(com.sample.SampleApp.R.id.button1);
...
button9 = (Button) activity.findViewById(com.sample.SampleApp.R.id.button9);
```

I tried to use reflection but the code looks unclean.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    String btnName = "button" + i;
    /* do reflection stuff to link self.buttonX 
       with a reference to com.sample.SampleApp.R.id.buttonX */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is untested, but give it a try:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[]{button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9};
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length, i++) {
   buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + i, "id", "com.sample.SampleApp"));
}
```

With ArrayList (again untested - just to give you an idea of what I mean):

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++) {
   buttons.add(new Button(this));
   buttons.get(i) = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + i, "id", "com.sample.SampleApp"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The getResources().getIdentifier() will help a lot, but is there a way to avoid the Button array?

Comment: I suppose you could clean it up a bit by using an ArrayList with Button elements, but I don't think you're going to get it more "clean" than that. I'd love to be proven wrong though :)

Comment: The ArrayList did not helped at all, but you helped me see that I did't needed instance variables to reference the UI elements if I could create a local variable to reference the tested UI element found by findViewById. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm thinking about it, ArrayList is probably a bad idea. I'm not sure if you can make it much better than the first suggestion.